# Rxjava, SubjectSubscriptionManager has too many subjectObserver

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I use a PublishSubject to make an RXBus.
When I send a message, call **subject.onNext**
And I use **subject.ofType.doOnNext** to register it.

Then I found when I register one and send messages for thousands times.
It becomes very slow. I add some log,and I know the SubjectObserver is too many.
The loop in PublishSubject.onNext cost lots of time.

Then I add a method to clear some used subject.

```
        public synchronized State removeFinishObserver(){
            SubjectObserver[] a = observers;
            SubjectObserver[] b = new SubjectObserver[a.length + 1];
            int index = 0;
            for(SubjectObserver observer:observers){
                LogUtils.d("onNextFinish:" + observer.onNextFinish);
                if(!observer.onNextFinish){
                    b[index] = observer;
                    index ++;
                }
            }
            SubjectObserver[] c = new SubjectObserver[index];
            return new State(terminated, c);
    }
```

But it doesn't work well,and even slower.I don't have idea to make it quickly.So I doubt anyone can help me.

======================some more======================

```
void sendNext();//after several millseconds, receive will happened,maybe timeout
void receive(){
    RxBus.getDefault().post(tmp);
}
RxBus.getDefault().toObservable(String.class)
            .doOnNext(s -> {
                    sendNext();
                }
            })
            .timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                if(throwable instanceof TimeoutException){
                    sendNext();
                }
            })
            .retry();
public class RxBus {
    private static volatile RxBus defaultInstance;

    private final Subject<Object, Object> bus;
    public RxBus() {
        bus = new SerializedSubject<>(PublishSubject.create());
    }

    public static RxBus getDefault() {
        if (defaultInstance == null) {
            synchronized (RxBus.class) {
                if (defaultInstance == null) {
                    defaultInstance = new RxBus();
                }
            }
        }
        return defaultInstance ;
    }
    public void post (Object o) {
        bus.onNext(o);
    }
    public <T> Observable<T> toObservable (Class<T> eventType) {
        return bus.ofType(eventType);
    }
}

compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.3'
```

Comment: Could you show the code you are actually using? SubjectSubscriptionManager is an internal-use class and it hosts active Subscribers in an array. Somehow, you don't seem to unsubscribe or you keep adding more Subscribers instead of working with those that already there. Also you may want to try `subject.take(1)` if you are interested in only 1 element per subscriber.

Comment: What code.Rxbus or where I use RXBus?

Comment: I've add the code,and when other things need to say is that I copied code from **SubjectSubscriptionManager** and  **PublishSubject**, and edit the RXBus to know what is wrong.And I cann't use take one,because I need wait this subject to execute recieve() for thouands times, and it will finish by other code. The code is to work with  usb device, so I can't change  **sendNext() and receive()**.

Comment: What RxJava version are you using? Also could you post something that demonstrates the problem you are facing - I don't see anything wrong with what you are showing now.

Comment: The problem is that when I execute **post() in RXBus** for about several ten thousands times, It will become very slow.And I copied  that two class,I found loop in **onNext() PublishSubject** costs lots of time. And the **SubjectSubscriptionManager.subjectObservers.length** become very large.I've add rxjava version in the question.

Comment: Could you write a **unit test** that demonstrates the problem - one that doesn't need an Android environment? If not, place a breakpoint on the SubjectSubscriptionManager.call and see what is adding more Subscribers every time.

Comment: Also this could be a reentrancy problem if you have syncrhonous source where the subscriber posts to the same RxBus from the same thread. I suggest, instead of post(), have a worker of the TrampolineScheduler and schedule the subject.onNext with it.

Comment: After I wrote some tests.I think I found the problem now.I wrote like this,then, the error happens.
**Observable.just()
.flatmap(s -> rxbus.toObservable(String.class))
.flatmap(s -> rxbus.toObservable(String.class))**,
The first toObservable do the things in the comments before, I write the second toObservable to make it stop.Then the error happens.And I need a device to test next day.Thank you for your help.Thank you very much.T T